# How to show only some elements of a table in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I wanna show the rows of this list when the id_alumno of the table "reserva" is equals to id_alumno loged-in.

--table Reserva

-- GridView reserva\index

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'fecha',
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: are you trying to say that you want to display the rows in the gridView where the id in the table is equal to logged in user id ?

Comment: Yes that is a good question, are you trying to show columns based on if the user authenticated?

Comment: yes just that :(

Comment: You don't need any exception like, when user is Admin or user with special permission can access all records?

Comment: the admin can see all "reservas", but profile "alumno" only can see his "reservas"

Comment: Do you have any identification for Admin like `is_admin` field? So you can distinguish between admin user and other users.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your "ReservaSearch.php" in your "search" function after the others "andFilterWhere"

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['id_alumno' => \Yii::$app->user->id]);
```

Comment: this is wrong and would not show all the records to the site admin, this is like hardcoding in the `searchModel` which isnt a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataProvider->query->where('reserva == id_alumno ')
```

You can add query in your Gridview Widget

Comment: i try this but i cant do it work correctly.

'dataProvider' => $dataProvider->query->where('id_reserva'==Yii::$app->user->identity->id_alumno),